# Multilanguage + Multistore Magento configuration

Tags: magento, multilingual

I've been scouting all over the web and this site, but have found no proper answer for this particular case scenario. I hope somebody can help out.

One Magento install. Two Stores, A and B. Each has two languages, say 'nl' and 'en' and one store view per language.

Store A is on www.store-a.com, Store B on www.store-b.com, multistore is configured and running fine.

But now on each of the two stores, i want '/en/' and '/nl/' to be the base for the two store views (languages).

I can simply name both views of store A 'en' and 'nl', and tick the option in the Configuration>Web screen to append the code to the url, but then of course, I cannot do the same with store B since the store views would have duplicate codes.

My guess is it's best to leave that option off, and work another solution... but what? :-)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you another way to manage it per website you should have store view.

Lets say for ex:

You website should like 
1) www.store-a.com 2) www.store-b.com,

And there you have to create stores(en/nl) for each of store and assign language to them store. from `system -> Configuration`

Just think twice when you need to implement multistore with multi language before you implement this.

here is official [tutorial by magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work) and you can also look https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/how-to-create-multiple-store-with-different-domain-in-magento

https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/30/How-to-Setup-Magento-with-Multiple-Stores-and-Domains.html

hope this will sure help you,

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Isn't this exactly what I'm describing above? Creating a store view per language is exactly what I did. The question is how to have both URL's be www.store-a.com/en AND www.store-b.com/en for English verson. Thanks.